# Can't update row on catch clause java hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Have this situation, have table `master_balance` store balance, create charge amount of balance then do some process on `try`, if got error on `catch` return the balance :

function charge() <-- call stored function on database where is charge the balance (balance - amount)

```
PERFORM 1 FROM master_balance where externalkey = $1 and tenant_record_id = $2 for update;

UPDATE master_balance
set balance = balance - $3
where id = (select t.id from master_balance t where t.externalkey = $1 and tenant_record_id = $2 order by id desc limit 1)
returning balance into newbalance;
```

function return() <-- call stored function on database where is return the balance (balance + amount)

```
PERFORM 1 FROM master_balance where externalkey = $1 and tenant_record_id = $2 for update;

UPDATE master_balance
set balance = balance + $3
where id = (select t.id from master_balance t where t.externalkey = $1 and tenant_record_id = $2 order by id desc limit 1)
returning balance into newbalance;
```

java :

```
try{
balance = charge(12, 1, 4);

//example balance is 5 after charge, and when i print the balance got 5 and the table updated with value 5

Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
invoice.setCurBalance(balance); //balance is 5

tx.commit() <--- error from here
}catch(Exception e)
{
back = return(12, 1, 4); //balance is 6

//try to print back, the value out is 6 but not updated on table
}
```

but i have the case, after charge the amount, when is going to catch, is return the right value but not updated the table, is catch clause can't do query ?

Comment: still no update

Comment: provide full log trace n proper code.